# cloudera docker images not found

Tags: docker, cloudera, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I downloaded the docker image of the *clouderaquickstart*. But when I used `docker images` command I am unable to see the image of clouderaquickstart. I even used the command `docker images -a` to see the images but it returned an empty list. I attached the screen shot below. Can someone please tell how to rectify this. Thanks in advance.

[image: Screenshot of terminal]

Comment: are you running out of disk space while doing `docker pull`? The cloudera quickstart images are quite big.

Comment: Yeah you are true, can you please tell me how can I remove the existing image and increase the space?